# How to make a flowchart for javascripts loops that deals with arrays

Tags: javascript, flowchart

I am making a flowchart for my project, I am stuck with this flowchart problem, with loops such as ( for I in an array). I tried looking online but there didn't exist any solution.

```js
  var country = {
   "Australia": AUS,
   "Japanese Yen": YEN,
   "Chinese Yuan": YAUN,
   "Indonesian Rupiah": RUPIAH
  };
  var i;
   rate = (val/countRate);
  for (var i in country){ 
   var currency =  (rate*country[i]);
   OUTPUT (i + "  $"currency);
     }
```

Comment: `rate` is not declared.  `countRate` is not defined.  `currency` is not declared.  `OUTPUT` is not defined. `"  $"currency` is not Javascript.

Comment: @Tibrogargan my original code works, this is a part of code, and I want to make a flow chart of that

Comment: You need to provide an [mcve] rather than asking people to go to the effort of reproducing your issue without any context.  It does not help that you do not explain what you are trying to achieve.